# How to declare an undeclared identifier with ADT and linked-lists

Tags: c++, linked-list, header-files, abstract-data-type, undeclared-identifier

Im a new programmer and am having difficulty with this in my header file linkedList.h:

I am trying to add

```
void divideAt(linkedListType<Type> &secondList, const Type& item);
```

to a class. this part if fine. next I move on to the definition (further down in the same header file. This is acceptable right? It doesn't have to be in a seperate implementation file?) Here is what I have:

```
template <class Type>
void linkedListType<Type::divideAt(linkedListType<Type> &secondList, const Type& item)
{
}
```

in what i believe is called the formal parameters my complied/IDE says 
1>c:\users...\linkedlist.h(227): error C2065: 'secondList' : undeclared identifier

Am I not declaring it in this line? I'm having difficulty figuring out where i've gone wrong or where to proceed. As I said I am new to programming, so please explain everything in detail. You'll be helping me learn and understand these concepts more.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I see I left out a bracket in the line. This corrected the problem.